# Invalid status code: LIMIT_UNEXPECTED_FILE - Multer Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multer

I'm trying to create a form where it will be a field to upload multiple images, like real estate site.

In Postman, I set the body to form-data and try to post two files to http://localhost:8080/api/files/upload while server is running to check if it is working before implementing the view in React, but getting this error:

Also addition information, I'm using

```
app.use("/api/files", imageRoutes); // => /api/files/
```

```
RangeError [ERR_HTTP_INVALID_STATUS_CODE]: Invalid status code: LIMIT_UNEXPECTED_FILE
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:393:5)
    at ServerResponse.writeHead (node:_http_server:343:11)
    at ServerResponse._implicitHeader (node:_http_server:334:8)
    at write_ (node:_http_outgoing:867:9)
    at ServerResponse.end (node:_http_outgoing:977:5)
    at ServerResponse.send (C:\Users\User\Downloads\yedy-react-backend-master\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:232:10)
    at ServerResponse.json (C:\Users\User\Downloads\yedy-react-backend-master\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:278:15)
    at C:\Users\User\Downloads\yedy-react-backend-master\server.js:35:7
    at Layer.handle_error (C:\Users\User\Downloads\yedy-react-backend-master\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:71:5)
    at trim_prefix (C:\Users\User\Downloads\yedy-react-backend-master\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:326:13)
```

**images-controllers.js**

```js
    const fs = require("fs")
    
    const uploadImage = (req, res, next) => {
        const files = req.files;
    
        if (! files) {
           res.status(400).send('Please choose files');
           return;        }
        // convert images into base64 encoding
        let imgArray = files.map((file) => {
            let img = fs.readFileSync(file.path)
    
            return encode_image = img.toString('base64')
        })
        let result = imgArray.map((src, index) => { // create object to store data in the collection
            let finalImg = {
                filename: files[index].originalname,
                contentType: files[index].mimetype,
                imageBase64: src
            }
    
            let newUpload = new UploadModel(finalImg);
    
            return newUpload.save().then(() => {
                return {msg: `${
                        files[index].originalname
                    } Uploaded Successfully...!`}
            }).catch(error => {
                if (error) {
                    if (error.name === 'MongoError' && error.code === 11000) {
                        return Promise.reject({error: `Duplicate ${
                                files[index].originalname
                            }. File Already exists! `});
                    }
                    return Promise.reject({
                        error: error.message || `Cannot Upload ${
                            files[index].originalname
                        } Something Missing!`
                    })
                }
            })
        });
    
        Promise.all(result).then(msg => { // res.json(msg);
            res.redirect('/')
        }).catch(err => {
            res.json(err);
        })
    }
    
    exports.uploadImage = uploadImage;
```

**multer.js**

```js
    const multer = require('multer');
    
    // set storage
    var storage = multer.diskStorage({
        destination : function ( req , file , cb ){
            cb(null, 'uploads')
        },
        filename : function (req, file , cb){
            // image.jpg
            var ext = file.originalname.substr(file.originalname.lastIndexOf('.'));
    
            cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + ext)
        }
    })
    
    module.exports = store = multer({ storage : storage })
```

**image-routes.js**

```js
    const express = require("express");
    const router = express.Router()
    const store = require("../middleware/multer")
    
    const imagesController = require("../controllers/images-controllers");
    
    router.post('/upload', store.array('images', 12), imagesController.uploadImage)
    
    module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are not sending images properly from the Postman. You should specify the name of images array to be `images` because you specified that in the Multer middleware.

You should send it like this:

[image]

Comment: I'm afraid it is still the same error even tho I entered the key. If I **use x-www-form-urlencoded** and type manually like aa.png it responds with the error  `'Please choose files'` from **images-controllers.js**. I really don't get why having this issue

Comment: Can you try to use `any` method of the Multer, that will allow you to upload any file names. `router.post('/upload', store.any(), imagesController.uploadImage)`?

Comment: Now I'm getting `Invalid status code: ENOENT`...

Comment: Oh wait... It's because you are trying to upload files in local `uploads` folder... And that folder probably does not exist... Can you  check that?

Comment: Yes, you were right! But the question is, imagine the user will fill the form, will they get the same error unless does not exists any folder named `uploads`?

Comment: Yeah, they will get the same error if the `uploads` folder does not exist on the server, since you are storing everything in the server itself. So, make sure that once you deploy the server, the `uploads` folder will be there.